# how to iterate and statically type values using JSON::Serializable?

Tags: crystal-lang

I have the followng code

```
require "json"

struct TreeData
  include JSON::Serializable
  include JSON::Serializable::Unmapped

  @increased_hp_percent : Float32?
  @value : Float32?
  @increased_strength : Float32?

end


puts TreeData.from_json(%({"1":{},"2":{"modifications":{"increased_hp_percent":5},"value":5},"3":{"value":10},"4":{"modifications":{"increased_hp_percent":15,"increased_strength":20}}}))
```

Which produces the following output:

```
TreeData(@json_unmapped={"1" => {}, "2" => {"modifications" => {"increased_hp_percent" => 5_i64}, "value" => 5_i64}, "3" => {"value" => 10_i64}, "4" => {"modifications" => {"increased_hp_percent" => 15_i64, "increased_strength" => 20_i64}}}, @increased_hp_percent=nil, @value=nil, @increased_strength=nil)
```

Basically, I want to set the values of the keys I specified (`increased_hp_percent`, `value`, and `increased_strength`) to `Float32`.

However, they are not getting set to the right type. I believe it's because they are inside another json object.

also I am trying to iterate through the json. If I were to use `JSON.parse`, then do `json.as_h.each` it would work fine. I don't know how to do this using the new [JSON::Serializable](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.27.0/JSON/Serializable.html)

You may ask why don't I just use JSON.parse? Well, because I want to statically type my json to the correct types. But I also want to be able to enumerate through it like before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to properly create types for your nested data structure, it doesn't try to dig them out for you:

```
require "json"

struct Modifications
  include JSON::Serializable

  getter increased_hp_percent : Float32?
  getter increased_strength : Float32?
end

struct TreeData
  include JSON::Serializable

  getter modifications : Modifications?
  getter value : Float32?
end

data = Hash(String, TreeData).from_json(%({"1":{},"2":{"modifications":{"increased_hp_percent":5},"value":5},"3":{"value":10},"4":{"modifications":{"increased_hp_percent":15,"increased_strength":20}}}))

data.each_value do |node|
  pp node
end
```

Output:

```
TreeData(@modifications=nil, @value=nil)
TreeData(
 @modifications=
  Modifications(@increased_hp_percent=5.0_f32, @increased_strength=nil),
 @value=5.0_f32)
TreeData(@modifications=nil, @value=10.0_f32)
TreeData(
 @modifications=
  Modifications(@increased_hp_percent=15.0_f32, @increased_strength=20.0_f32),
 @value=nil)
```

Comment: Awww. Makes sense now, thank you so much. Gonna use this  way on my other JSON data as well, awesome.